# less +F but tracking file by name, not inode

Tags: linux, unix, less

I'm looking at log file but it's renamed (logs rotation mechanism). How do I see actual logging file in `less`-like fashion, so I can stop updating for a while and then continue?

Comment: Are you looking for a Windows client/tool? Or something *nix related? If you're looking at something for Windows, I can recommend BareTail https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks for suggestion but I was asking about Unix/Linux. I've updated the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tail -F /path/to/logfile | less`

Comment: It doesn't work... I have to exit and run this again. What does `tail -F` sends to pipe when it detects that file has been replaced?

Comment: The contents of the new file.